# Modal is not showing with a href

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-modal, typeerror

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal modal-cover fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

and this is href tag that I want to show the modal when I click it.

```
<a href="#staticBackdrop" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at Object.findOne (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:9266)
    at Hi._showElement (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:51520)
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:50581
    at _ (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:2145)
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:47626
    at _ (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:2145)
    at HTMLDivElement.a (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:2518)
```

I got the bug. How can I solve this?

Comment: Check the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/. Your modal does not have the correct structure.